# BUILD FAILED in 3s Command: D:\Flutter\myfarmer\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My code working perfectly before I will be add cloud firestore plugin but after I will be added this plugin and i get this error

````
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\Flutter\myfarmer\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Flutter\myfarmer\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: D:\Flutter\myfarmer\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.```
````

Comment: Could you please share your build.gradle file for both root and app level?

Comment: Can you please include the Stacktrace of the error for further information?

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your gradle make sure you are using google the old google-services 4.2.0

in android/build.gradle

`dependencies {
         ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
         ...
    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287148/flutter-firebase-onclick-data-send-new-screen

Answer (score 0):

update flutter or use other version of gradle by changing the class path in my case this was worked

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

hope it helps you